# How to overcome 'Exceeded maximum execution time' in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I think I should start by saying that I am a complete **noob** to all of this. Currently, I have this system where I upload .csv-s to my Google Drive and after I run a time-triggered script, they get transferred to a Google Spreadsheet file. The problem is that in recent times my .csv-s started getting slightly larger and triggered the 'Exceeded maximum execution time' pop up. I was wondering if you could help me find a workaround? I have attached my script, which in turn is based on various small scripts I found on this website.

Is there a way I could maybe transfer just two columns (say A and F)?

```html
function importData() {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B24o3jJdWKZ2Mk5KaVBkX0"); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  
  
  
   

 var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KxvCe4zyiYCxvjFEpCelQpB85kABpFE4gy77");
 var sheetA = ssA.getSheets()[0];

 var rangeA = sheetA.getRange("a1:a10");

 var cellA = rangeA.getCell(7, 1);
 Logger.log(cellA.getValue()); //last few rows are used to get the URL of my .csv (that has to get converted) from a sheet that serves as an inventory
 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName(cellA.getValue());
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KxvCe4zyiYCxvjFEpCelQpB85kABpFE4gy77"); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data

  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if the previously referenced .csv file exists in the reports folder
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
    
    
    
    
    var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheetB = ssB.getSheetByName('NEWDATA');
    ssB.deleteSheet(sheetB);
    
    
    
   
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet('NEWDATA'); // create a 'NEWDATA' sheet to store imported data
    // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'NEWDATA' sheet
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      newsheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
   
    //** report data is now in 'NEWDATA' sheet in the spreadsheet - process it as needed,
      
    
  }
};



// This will parse a delimited string into an array of arrays.

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ) {

  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );

  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;

  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
};
```

Comment: you wont be able to workarround it if the issue is a huge csv file. you would need to upload the csv as many smaller files and process one by one. but also the question is offtopic as its asking us to modify code you found, not something you attempted to modify and has errors we could help fix. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. Do you know if there is a way I could transfer maybe just two columns (say A and B)?

Comment: Yes, you can try that. You can also try to build a single two-dimensional array and write it all at once. Currently you write many (csvData.length) little 1-dimensional arrays in the loop that says "// loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'NEWDATA' sheet". See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices under "use batch operations". This forum can help you once you show us issues with your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

My co-worker told me to be brave and run the same code again -- the error message was gone because Google appeared to have learned that I needed more time, up to 30 minutes.

Good luck and try that again. It worked in my case.